# Получение ссылки на DOM элемент при клике

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо, чтобы при клике на любой dom элемент возвращалась его ссылка в формате `div#id.class`. (c использование библиотеки jquery). Подскажите как можно это реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('*').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  var _this = $(this).context;
  var tag = _this.tagName.toLowerCase();
  var id = (i = _this.id) ? ('#' + i) : '';
  var _class = (c = _this.className) ? ('.' + c) : '';
  console.log(tag + id + _class);
})
```

```css
#id {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
}
#id2 {
  background: #c0c;
}
.class {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0cc;
}
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div id="id2" class="class"></div>
```

Comment: как раз то что нужно, спасибо)